# Definition of Compactification in Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, compactification

> If $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $X$ is a proper subspace of $Y$ whose closure equals $Y$, then $Y$ is said to be **compactification** of $X$. If $Y-X$ is a single point, then $Y$ is called the **one point compactification** of $X$.

**Claim:** $X$ has a one point compactification $Y$ $\Leftrightarrow $ $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff and $X$ is not compact. **Proof:** Condition $\overline{X}=Y$ is equivalent to $X$ is not compact. Proof of $X$ is not compact $\Rightarrow$ $\overline{X}=Y$, link: [Theorem 29.1 of Munkres’ Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4426018/861687) (last part). Conversely, assume towards contradiction, $X$ is compact. Then $\infty=Y-X \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. So $\infty \in \mathcal{N}_\infty$. Thus $X \cap \{ \infty \} =\emptyset$. Which contradicts our initial assumption of $\overline{X}=Y$. **Is this proof correct?**

What the following sentence means: We speak of $Y$ as “the” one point compactification because $Y$ is uniquely determined up to a homeomorphism.

Comment: Your claim is poorly stated. The right hand side of the claim ---  namely the statement *$X$ is locally compact Hausdorff and $X$ is not compact* --- does not refer to $Y$ at all.

Comment: @LeeMosher that’s how written in book

Comment: No, that's not how it's written in the book.  The book says "$X$ has a one-point compactification $Y$ if and only if ..."

Comment: @DanVelleman then what is difference between $X$ has a one point compactification $Y$ and $Y$ is one point compactification of $X$. I thought they are same.

Comment: The logical difference is this. In one case you are asserting **THERE EXISTS $Y$** *such that $Y$ is the one point compactification of $X$*; that's a true--false statement (assuming $X$ is given). In the other case, the existential quantifier is missing: *$Y$ is the one point compactification of $X$* is a statement about a space $Y$; in this statement $Y$ is a free variable, and the statement may be true for some particular spaces $Y$ and false for others.

Comment: @LeeMosher ohhh….. you have 220 iq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What the following sentence means: We speak of Y as “the” one point compactification because Y is uniquely determined up to a homeomorphism.

It means:

1. Say that $X$ is a non-compact, locally-compact Hausdorff space
2. Say that Y is a compact space containing $X$ and one additional point, $\infty_Y$
3. Say that Z is a compact space containing $X$ and one additional point, $\infty_Z$

> **Then $Y$ and $Z$ are homeomorphic.**

Munkres then gives a construction that explains how to take $X$ and construct the corresponding $Y$.  And because $Y$ is uniquely determined, that one construction is the whole story; there are no other ways to produce a one-point compactification of a space.

Munkres’ presentation of this is a little hard to follow.  [What is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692690/what-is-the-one-point-compactification-of-mathbbz/692696#692696) discusses it and may help a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I haven’t read full answer yet. I’m wondering, why you answer this question as community wiki.

Comment: $Y$ and $Z$ are compact Hausdorff, I think.